# Select Range based on column "values" (values being a date)

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code:

```
Sub Asia()
    Dim d1 As Date, wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    d2 = wf.WorkDay(Date, -3)
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=
        "C:\Desktop\Book1.xlsm"
    Range("A242:F244").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Book2.xlsm").Activate
    Range("A242").Select
    ActivateSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

I am selecting `Range("A242:F244")` in which column `A` cells are dates (dd/mm/yyyy).
And I am pasting these dates in another xlsm file.

I would like to select the `Range()`, but instead of giving the cell coordinates, I would like to give the `Range()` `d2` which is the current working day minus 3 days (Today-3).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `Range.AutoFilter` maybe and select visible cells? It's a little confusing what you're trying to do. Are all the dates in `A242:F244` the same? Or are they the range of today -> today -3?

Comment: No, the dates are in column A1:A...
My code is A242:F244, so that I am selecting cells A242 (=(Today-3)),  A243 (=(Today-2)) and  A244 (=(Today-1)) ---> this is for today. Tomorrow the dates I want will be A243, A244 and A245

Comment: Use `Range.Find` or `Application.Match` on column A, trying to find today, i.e. `Date`. Then use `Resize` to grab that cell plus the next 2.

Comment: Or you can find `Range("D2").Value` and use `Resize`  to grab the appropriate range.

Comment: But my `"D2"`  is not a cell, my `d2` is a constant `d2 = wf.WorkDay(Date, -3)`

Comment: Oh sorry I missed that line in your code. Then just use `d2` with `Range.Find` or `Application.Match`.